# How To Iterate An RXJS Observable Array Of Objects [{},{}...] in Angular 8+ and push each Object's Properties To The Template One Object At A Time

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, rxjs

The goal is to parse an observable array of 10 objects, which contain HTML anchor properties, and push them **one object at a time** (id, url, title) in order to populate an animated template, then next object.

I am pulling a JSON Array (JSON.stringify({results})) from an AWS Lambda function through the AWS API Gateway via Angular's HTTPClient.

The Array Object Looks Like This:

````
```
{
results: [{id: any, url: 'string', title: 'string'}, {id: any, url: 'string', title: 
'string'},...}]
}
````

````
The Template Looks Like This:

    ```
    <div class="primary" #elmRef>
      <div class="secondary" *ngFor="let anchor of (this.newsObj$ | async)" id="{{anchor.id}}">
        <a href="{{anchor.url}}">{{anchor.title}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
````

The Schema/Model/Interface Looks Like This:

```
export interface Nstream {
      id: any;
      title: string;
      link: string;
}
```

This Is The API Service:

```
loadAllNews$(): Observable<Nstream[]> {
  return this.http.get<Nstream[]>('https://example.com/stage/{proxy+}')
    .pipe(
      map(response => response['results']),
      shareReplay());
}
```

This Is The Component:

```
export class NewsStreamComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {


  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<Nstream[]>([]);  // remembers the last array obj it emitted
  newsObjs$ = this.subject.asObservable();
  @ViewChild('elmRef', {static: false}) elmRef;

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  obj$: Observable<any>;


  // onAnimationStart(event) {---TBD---}
  // onAnimationEnd(event) {---TBD---}

ngOnInit() {
    this.newsObjs$ = this.api.loadAllNews$()
      .pipe(
        map((response) => response));
  }

//  This is where I left off
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.obj$ = this.newObjs$.pipe(
    switchMap(response => response),
      map(values => values),
    take(1));
  }
// this.obj$.subscribe(v => console.log('first instance of endpoint from object obj$: ',  v));
}
```

PLEASE NOTE: I'm most concerned about how to iterate and populate the template at this time.  I will figure out the animation stuff later as I supplied it only to provide some context.

CURRENTLY: I can populate the template, however, only within the ngOnInit function and with all 10 objects piled on top of each other, which is what I want (I think). I took this approach assuming I'd be able to iterate through the ids of the objects, surfacing one, and using it to toggle an ngIf on the template, thus showing only the template with matching ids in the ngAfterViewInit().  After more than a few hours of trying and searching I am throwing in the towel and looking for some help.  Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Just Gona throw out there... if the goal is to animate entry, you’re better off doing it with css. You can use css rules to sequence animations, adding a delay to each successive item.

Comment: Thank you for your response @bryan60 - essentially I will be using css to animate.  My issue has more to do with drilling into the rxjs observable in order to surface the nested information I need to animate.

Comment: I'm unclear on your objectives then here. if you try and clarify your actual goal behavior a little, I can help out.  you have a list of items, and you want to show them one at a time? with some kind of button or gesture toggling between them?

Comment: Thanks again for your input @bryan60, I apologize if I was unclear. In the "Please Note:" section at the bottom of my question I pointed out that I was most concerned about iterating and would figure out the animation afterward.  Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: I caught that but my thinking is that you might have an AB problem here as the approach looks off (this operator doesn't exist bc it's a very strange rxjs usage), and could maybe be improved if i understood the goal better, but if you’re happy, go for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slightly less manual build of this functionality if it's what your after:

```
this.newsObjs$ = this.api.loadAllNews$().pipe(
  switchMap(values => from(values)),
  concatMap(value => timer(500).pipe(mapTo(value)))
)
```

or

```
this.newsObjs$ = this.api.loadAllNews$().pipe(
  switchMap(values => from(values)),
  concatMap(value => of(value).pipe(delay(500)))
)
```

both function the same. not a difference between them. could also pull it off with a `switchMap` into a `concat` of the array mapped into the same observables inside the `concatMap` operators above

Comment: Elegant answer @bryan60 really what I was attempting to accomplish, a pure rxjs solution. I like the way you used the "from" and "of" functions, I didn't think to do it that way. Note: I did have to change "of(value)" to "of([value])" in order to have it work with the *ngFor - now it works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // this will emit an observable each 500ms
  this.newsObjs$ = this.api.loadAllNews$().pipe(
    switchMap((values) => new Observable(observer => {
      if(!(values && values.length)) {
        observer.complete();
      }

      let index = 0;
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if(index < values.length) {
          observer.next(values[index++]);
        } else {
          observer.complete();
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 500);
    }))
  );
}
```

But why don't you use [stagger animation](https://angular.io/guide/complex-animation-sequences#animate-multiple-elements-using-query-and-stagger-functions)? It's baked inside @angular/animations.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response @julianobrasil - This is exactly what I need.  I thought there would be a more rxjs operator-centric method that I was missing, but your solution performs perfectly. Thank you!  All that said, I've taken a look at the stagger animation method you pointed out.  I think that approach has merit as I feel its a more natural solution.  Thank you again for you time and solutions.

Comment: You can always turn it into a custom operator, as we don't have an out-of-the-box "pace" operator. :D